# What is the difference between JAVA_HOME and update-alternatives?

Tags: java, alternatives

I have been trying to figure out the best way to run OpenJDK Java Runtime as default Java for my Fedora box and use Oracle JDK 6 for Android development namely for running Android SDK Manager, Android Studio and Eclipse from Android Bundle.

I installed OpenJDK Java Runtime from the Fedora repository which has setup alternatives as follow.

```
[donnie@fedora ~]$ alternatives --list | grep java
jre_openjdk             auto    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.5.1.fc20.x86_64/jre
jre_1.7.0               auto    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.5.1.fc20.x86_64/jre
java                    auto    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.5.1.fc20.x86_64/jre/bin/java
libjavaplugin.so.x86_64 auto    /usr/lib64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

I have installed the Oracle JDK 6 using the rpm provided by Oracle.

I could make Android Bundle and Studio make use of JAVA_HOME to run under Oracle JDK by sticking following in `.bashrc`.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I noticed that Chrome still uses OpenJDK (as I still need to link the plugin).

What are the difference between JAVA_HOME and using alternatives?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Alternatives

Alternatives is a tool that will manage the locations of the installed software using links under the control of the `alternatives` tool.

These links are ultimately managed under `/etc/alternatives` with intermediate links created under a directory in `$PATH`, typically `/usr/bin`.

#### Example

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Feb 24 17:36 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 73 Feb 24 17:36 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.5.0.fc19.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

#### $JAVA_HOME

`$JAVA_HOME` is where software can be told to look through the use of an environment variable. Adding it to the `$PATH` simply adds the executables present in `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `$PATH`. This is sometimes necessary for certain applications.

The 2 mechanisms are related but can be used together or independent of each other, it really depends on the Java application which mechanism is preferable.

#### What I do

I typically use `$JAVA_HOME` for some GUI applications, but in general use it only for server installations that make use of Jetty, Tomcat, or JBOSS, for example.

For these installations I'll still use `alternatives` to manage the Java installations prior to setting the `$JAVA_HOME`. I like doing it this way in cases where I might need to have multiple installations of Java.

Alternatives does allow you to have certain tools use one installation of Java while other tools use a completely different one.

#### References

- [5 Minute Guide to using the alternatives Command on Fedora/CentOS/RHEL](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/5562/5-minute-guide-to-using-the-alternatives-command-on-fedoracentosrhel/)
- [Using 'Alternatives' in Linux to use a different Java package](http://tech.lanesnotes.com/2008/03/using-alternatives-in-linux-to-use.html)

Comment: The giveaway is that with alternatives I can use different components of Java. For example, Alternatives can set `java` and `javac` from different JDKs on the other hand `JAVA_HOME=JAVALOCATION` would point `java`, `javac`, and `javaws` to `java`, `javac` and `javaws` in `JAVALOCATION`, respectively.

Comment: The reason I asked this [question](http://goo.gl/qmcqEx) was how can I use OpenJDK as default Java Runtime and make Android Studio, Eclipse and SDK Manager use Oracle JDK. I can run those three programs under Oracle JDK by hard editing their startup scripts which might get broken if they are updated. I was looking for something more generic like `STUDIO_JDK`, that I can add to `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`, that is used by Android Studio for picking up JDK but I think Android Bundle (Eclipse and SDK Manager) won't honor that.

Comment: @donniezazen - yeah `STUDIO_JDK` is a custom thing. I would use alternatives for those tools and set `JAVA_HOME`to the path under `/usr/bin` which is managed by `alternatives`. When upgrades are performed, changing `alternatives` is all that's required.

Comment: I am not sure what you are proposing. Point both `alternatives` and `JAVA_HOME` to say `/usr/bin/java`. Also it seems like `JAVA_HOME` overrides `alternatives`.

Comment: @donniezazen - yes use alternatives to manage your JAVA installs and then use `JAVA_HOME`, pointing it to `/usr/bin`. You're correct, `JAVA_HOME` can operate independently from `alternatives`.

Comment: What are we trying to accomplish by pointing `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/bin`? `/usr/bin` contains java binaries managed by `alternatives`. `JAVA_HOME` would be redundant in the case you are suggesting. And either `OpenJDK` or `Oracle JDK` will become system default. Whereas I want OpenJDK as default and Oracle JDK for Android development.

Comment: @donniezazen - yes but some applications will only utilize Java through `JAVA_HOME`. Often times this is app servers such as JBoss or Jetty. They have stop/start service scripts that need `JAVA_HOME` defined. GUI apps too will often times need `JAVA_HOME`. It's hit or miss which fall into this category so it's often easier to just define it up front for the box.

Comment: Thanks @slm you have been very helpful. It seems like there is no generic way to achieve what i want to do. I think i will go ahead and use OpenJDK's Icedtea for chrome for security and Oracle JDK as system default as Android development takes precedence.