# "-bash: javac: command not found" error after installing OpenJDK 1.7

Tags: centos, software-installation, java

I have CentOS 6.7. I have installed Java 1.8. When I do Java -version I see the following output.

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I need javac so I came to know that this is available only if I install JDK. So I installed JDK by executing the following command

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

The installation was successful. But now when I again execute the command java -version, I see the old result. If I try to execute javac at the command prompt I see the error **'-bash: javac: command not found'**.  I observed that OpenJDK was installed to the directory /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/bin. So, I set it to JAVA_HOME, but I still cannot execute javac command. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Although setting `JAVA_HOME` is necessary for running Java, executables are still searched in `$PATH`, not in `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.

Comment: I set the directory in the PATH variable, but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this issue by executing the following command. I was not setting the PATH variable properly. I executed the following two commands and my problem was fixed.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Another approach is to use the alternatives system, per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598398/5132 , which wlll yield a symbolic link at `/usr/bin/javac`, with `/usr/bin` almost certainly already being on your path.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123424/5132 .