# alternatives java -OpenJDK RHEL

Tags: rhel, java, alternatives

I have the following setup (on multiple machines with RHEL7):

```bsh
$ which java 
/usr/bin/java

$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/java 
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

$ ls -ltr /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242b08-1.e17.x86_64/jre/bin/java

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk

$ ls -ltr /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk -> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-1.e17.x86_64
```

I need to update to version `251` so I took the corresponding `.tar.gz`  from artifactory , extract it in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.251` and now I need to update all the simlink in order to use the latest java version.

Using the man pages of alternatives I did:

`alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.251/bin/java`

Which modified `/etc/alternatives/java` but due to the fact that `$JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk` I need to modify/update `/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk` .

I am not sure what to put as the `<link>` in `alternatives --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>` in order to update `/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk`.

I'm not even sure that this is the correct approach towards updating java version . Thx

Comment: You don't need to create any symlinks. All you need to do is prepend `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.251/bin` to your `PATH` and `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.251/lib` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then set the `JAVA_HOME` as `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.251`.

Comment: You could also upgrade your RHEL systems, the current version of OpenJDK 8 in RHEL 7 is 262.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct approach to hand-inserting an *alternative* in the alternatives system.

Your `alternatives` tool is a port of the original Debian `update-alternatives` tool.
With that tool, and your port, there is

```
update-alternatives --display jre_1.8.0_openjdk
```

which should tell you the "generic name" to use with `--install`.
The vanilla Debian tool also has

```
update-alternatives --query jre_1.8.0_openjdk
```

for a machine-readable form that can be used in pipelines, which your system does not have, however.

**However:** On RHEL, Java installations are installed with the `--slave` option to `--install` so that the JRE is switched in lockstep with the `java` program.
In fact, there are between 20 and 50 `--slave` options that the install scripts for the packages set up.
Witness the likes of [this post-install script template for OpenJDK from AdoptOpenJDK](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-installer/blob/master/linux/rpm/config/jdk-8-openj9/postinst.sh) (which isn't even setting up a JRE alternative, notice) for example.

Really this isn't something that you are going to be able to construct, error-free, longhand, to match what you already have.
Don't download and install from raw TAR archives.
Use the packages.