# Java is running from /usr/java/latest/bin/java instead of /usr/bin/java

Tags: centos, rpm, java, alternatives

I have the latest version of Java installed on my system.

- But I wonder why when I run any program, the location from where java executes is `/usr/java/latest/bin/java` instead of `/usr/bin/java`.

  ```
  [prompt ~]$ which java
  /usr/bin/java

  [prompt ~]$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jul 23 15:13 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

  [prompt ~]$ ps -ef | grep tomcat
  www      11279     1  0 Jul23 ?        00:02:12 /usr/java/latest/bin/java -D...
  ```

Is there a way that I can set where `java` should execute from?

- (In my case, I want it to execute from `/usr/bin/java`)

Comment: Possible Dup - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123412/what-is-the-difference-between-java-home-and-update-alternatives/123424#123424

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java`. What is `/etc/alternatives/java` a symbolic link to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my surprise, even though my environment profile files did not have any setting of `JAVA_HOME`, it was pointing to `/usr/java/latest`:

```
[prompt ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/latest
[prompt ~]$ printenv | grep JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
```

No wonder why it was actually executing `java` from `/usr/java/latest` directory.

All I did was remove the entry in environment variables and the issue was fixed, `java` began executing from `/usr/bin/java`.